# Probababilty question about matches and their chance of working

Tags: probability

The problem is this:

> Four matches are left in a packet,
>
> 3 of the matches work independently with a probability 4/5
>
> One is defective and only works with probability 3/10
>
> You light all four and find out that 3 worked and one didn't. What's
>   the probability that the old one was the one that failed?

I'm not sure what I should do but I'm told the answer is not 7/13.
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Well, can you compute the probability that exactly one would fail?  That's your denominator.  The numerator is the probability that the bad one failed and all three good ones worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say $w$ are working matches and $d$ are defective, and $f$ indicates failure.

$P(wf)=\frac{2}{10}$

$P(df)=\frac{7}{10}$

Given that exactly one has failed you have four possibilities:

3 ways in which a good one can have failed and the rest worked:

$(\frac{8}{10})^2\cdot\frac{2}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{10}$

And one way in which the defective one failed and all the good ones worked:

$(\frac{8}{10})^3\cdot\frac{7}{10}$

The sum of these is the total probability space and the case of the bad one failing is the space you wish to measure (the tens cancel):

$\displaystyle\frac{8^3\cdot7}{(8^3\cdot7)+3\cdot(8^2\cdot2\cdot3)}=\frac{28}{37}$

Comment: You said "3 ways in which a good one can have failed" but I don't think you included that in your final calculation.

Comment: @David yes just realised that! Thanks.

Comment: right that makes alot of sense this came up part way though a question about distributions which really threw me off i though it might be some kind of geometric distribution what with the successes and failures thing

Comment: @user512254 Common theme with these questions is they first need rewriting it in as structured a way as possible; e.g. to be awkward they gave you the $p$ for one type of match and $1-p$ for the other match.